# Fast text editor / word processor for Windows that supports basic tables

Tags: windows, text-editor, word-processor, text, rtf

I have been using [Jarte Plus](https://www.jarte.com/) as my go-to text editor / word processor to create and edit simple documents.  I like that it's a portable application, very fast to load, and has a small memory footprint.  It supports RTF documents as well as basic tables.

Unfortunately, it's based on the native Windows rich text control, which is known to be quite buggy *(which I can confirm!)*.  Jarte is also no longer under development, and its source code has not been made open by the developer.

So I'm seeking recommendations for a new go-to text editor / word processor.

The documents I will be writing with this application will typically be 1-20 pages long, and do not require advanced features like headers/footers/footnotes/forms/indices.

***Here are the requirements:***

1. Very fast to open with a low memory footprint (so LibreOffice/OpenOffce Writer and Electron applications are not options)
2. Support basic tables (add/remove/resize columns and rows)
3. Support changing foreground color of text entered (red text, green text, et. al.)
4. Support **bold** and *italicized* text
5. Have a dark mode / dark theme which makes the application's UI dark as well as the page on which you are writing
6. WYSIWYG
7. Compatible with Windows 7-10
8. Must not rely on Microsoft's rich text control (or has functionality to overcome its bugs!)

***Preferences (not requirements):***

1. Portable (no writing to registry or files outside of its folders)
2. Open-source
3. Gratis (all prices considered)
4. Spell-checker
5. Support RTF format

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349827/using-tables-in-rtf

Comment: @EricS Thanks. Definitely an interesting read.  Although I *do appreciate* the reference, I'm thinking it's not really relevant as I am not going to write the code to create the editor. (Been there, done that!) :)

Comment: What I was wondering was whether RTF supports tables at all. If not then there would be no possible answer.

Comment: @EricS Ah, I see. Yes, RTF definitely supports tables!

Comment: An idea off the top of my head: Write your files in [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) and then use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert to RTF. (Markdown files are plain-text, so you can use whatever editor you want.)